# C++: when we should use "this->" PLUS parameters by reference

Tags: c++

suppose we have a class

```
class Foo {
private:
        int PARTS;
public:
        Foo( Graph & );
        int howBig();
}

int Foo::howBig() { return this->PARTS; }
int Foo::howBig() { return PARTS;       }
Foo::Foo( Graph &G ) {
    <Do something with G.*>
}
```

Which one of howBig()-variants is correct?
The &-sign ensures that only the *reference* for Graph object
is passed to initialization function?
In C I would simply do something like some_function( Graph *G ),
but in C++ we have both & and *-type variables, never understood
the difference...

Thank you.

Comment: Both are correct. And yes, the &-sign ensures that only the reference for `Graph` object is passed.

Comment: Perhaps starting with a good book would be a good idea; understanding the basics of the C++ type system is essential if you want to do any serious programming.

Answer (score 3):

When you've local variable inside a member function, then you **must have** to use `this` as:

```
 Foo::MemberFunction(int a)
 {
      int b = a;  //b is initialized with the parameter (which is a local variable)
      int c = this->a; //c is initialized with member data a
      this->a = a; //update the member data with the parameter
 }
```

But when you don't have such cases, then `this` is implicit; you need to explicity write it, which means in your code, both versions of `howBig` is correct.

However, in member initialization list, the rules are different. For example:

```
struct A
{
   int a;
   A(int a) : a(a) {}
};
```

In this code, `a(a)` means, the member data `a` is being initialized with the parameter `a`. You don't have to write `this->a(a)`. Just `a(a)` is enough. Understand this visually:

```
   A(int a) : a ( a ) {}
   //         ^   ^
   //         |   this is the parameter
   //         this is the member data
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `this->` to resolve the [dependent name](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#base-lookup) issue without explicitly having to spell out the name of the base. If the name of the base is big this could arguably improve readability.

This issue only occurs when writing templates and using `this->` is only appropriate if they're member functions, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
struct bar {
    void func();
};

template <typename T>
struct foo : public bar {
    void derived()
    {
        func(); // error
        this->func(); // fine
        bar<T>::func(); // also fine, but potentially a lot more verbose
    }
};
```

Comment: Should mention that dependent names pop up when writing member functions of a template class.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one of howBig()-variants is correct?

both in your case, the compiler will produce the same code

> The &-sign ensures that only the reference for Graph object is passed to initialization function? In C I would simply do something like some_function( Graph *G ), but in C++ we have both & and *-type variables, never understood the difference...

there is no difference as per the use of the variable inside the method(except syntax) - in the case of reference(&) imagine as if you've been passed an invisible pointer that you can use without dereferencing
it(the &) might be "easier" for clients to use

Comment: There is big difference. References can't be rebound.

Comment: Also, references can't be null, and unambiguously refer to a single object, while a pointer might refer to an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both forms of `Foo::howBig()` are correct. I tend to use the second in general, but there are situations that involve templates where the first is required.
2. The main difference between references and pointers is the lack of "null references". You can use reference arguments when you don't want to copy the whole object but you want to force the caller to pass one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Both are correct. Usually shorter code is easier to read, so only use `this->` if you need it to disambiguate (see the other answers) or if you would otherwise have trouble understanding where the symbol comes from.
2. References can't be rebound and can't be (easily) bound to NULL, so:

   1. Prefer references to pointers where you can use them. Since they cannot be null and they cannot be deleted, you have fewer things to worry about when using code that uses references.
   2. Use const references instead of values to pass objects that are large (more than say 16 or 20 bytes) or have complex copy constructors to save copy overhead while treating it as if it was pass by value.
   3. Try to avoid return arguments altogether, whether by pointer or reference. Return complex object or `std::pair` or `boost::tuple` or `std::tuple` (C++11 or TR1 only) instead. It's more readable.